# Which tense suits best with "Over the next decade" time expression?

Tags: grammar

In a grammar question, answer key says "Over the next decade, politicians will be keenly watching USA to see how it deals with increasing crime rates." . It uses future progressive to express that action isn't completed but I thınk answer should be future perfect tense because "over the next decade" states a finished action. Thanks for advance.

Comment: Future continuous and future perfect are differently, at least slightly.

Comment: The answer is correct. "Over the next decade" means from 2020 to 2030 (or 10 years into the future). This is not "a finished action". The future perfect could be used to say what will be possible at the end of the period. For example: "_In 2030 politicians will have watched (or: will have been watching) the USA for 10 years to see how it deals with increasing crime rates._"

Answer (score -2):

It's not a finished action. The action is just beginning and will continue for a decade.

Do not use *Thanks for advance*. It's not standard.

Do not use *Thanks in advance*. It's not needed because it's obviously in advance.

Use *Thanks*, *Thank you*, or *Many thanks*. Those are standard and correct.